# Dropdown box in PHP + HTML without SQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

Our goal is to **add a dropdown box in a wordpress contact section template that currently has only text fields.** We want to find the simplest way of achieving this - without involving any SQL (keep the static values in the php).

I believe the form uses AJAX to send the completed form.

You can see the form here (bottom of page) : http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/wp/jarvis/callouts/

From what we see, the form currently consists of two parts -  in **functions.php**:

```
wp_localize_script( 'rnrscripts', 'rnr_global_vars', array( 
        'contact_form_required_fields_label_ajax' =>  __('This is a required field', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contact_form_warning' => __('Please verify fields and try again.', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contact_form_email_warning' =>  __('Please enter a valid e-mail address and try again.', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contact_form_error' => __('There was an error sending your email. Please try again later.', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contact_form_success_message' => __('Thanks, we got your mail and will get back to you soon!', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contactFormDefaults_name' => __('Name', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contactFormDefaults_email' => __('E-mail', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contactFormDefaults_subject' => __('Subject', 'rocknrolla'),
        'contactFormDefaults_message' => __('Message', 'rocknrolla'),
        'commentFormDefaults_author' => __('Name', 'rocknrolla'),
        'commentFormDefaults_email' => __('E-mail', 'rocknrolla'),
        'commentFormDefaults_url' => __('http://', 'rocknrolla'),
        'searchFormDefaults_search' => __('Search', 'rocknrolla')
    ) );                

    }
```

and the **contact-section.php** (the wordpress page template for contact forms)

```
<!-- START CONTACT FORM -->
                       <div id="contact-form">      



                <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" class="contactForm form" id="contact-form">      


                              <div id="contact-input">
                              <input type="text" name="contactName" class="required" id="contactName" value="<?php _e('Name', 'rocknrolla'); ?>" />
                              <input type="text" name="contactEmail" class="required" id="contactEmail" value="<?php _e('E-mail', 'rocknrolla'); ?>" />
                              <input type="text" name="contactSubject" class="required" id="contactSubject" value="<?php _e('Subject', 'rocknrolla'); ?>" />
                              </div>


                              <div id="contact-textarea">
                              <textarea  class="required" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" rows="" cols=""><?php _e('Message', 'rocknrolla'); ?></textarea>
                              <textarea  class="required" name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" rows="" cols=""><?php _e('Message', 'rocknrolla'); ?></textarea>
                              <div>

                              <div id="contact-submit">
                              <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                              <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Send', 'rocknrolla'); ?>" class="comment-submit button submit" id="submitform" />

                              <span id="msg"></span>


                              </div>
                            </form> 
                           <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                      <!-- END CONTACT FORM -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Tomanow How to add a drop-down box. See the first line of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery. It would be easier. If you want to add a new field and if you will be able to alter the backend this is the code:

```
 $('form#contact-form').append('<select name="somename"><option>First Value</option><option>Second Value</option></select>');
```

If you won't alter the backend and replace one of the textareas this is the code (assuming subject field):

```
$('#contactSubject').remove();
$('form#contact-form').append('<select name="contact-subject" id="contactSubject"><option>First Value</option><option>Second Value</option></select>');
```

Also, if you want to keep all the fields but add a new one without altering the backend, i would suggest you to handle the form submit and add the new selectbox value to the end of any fields you want. For this one you can use this code:

```
    $(document).on('submit', 'form#contact-form', function(){
                //I'm assuming you would like to add the new select box value to contact message field.
                contactMessage = $('#contactMessage');
                currentValueForMessage = contactMessage.val();
                //Add new value
                newValue = currentValueForMessage+$('#newAddedSelectBoxID').val();
                contactMessage.val(newValue);

                //Now get all the form values and do the rest
                //Do the post request to $('form#contact-form').prop('action'); 
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm wondering if this would play well with the existing php functions that we have for the existing form? ie: would adding this in jquery send the newly populated value together with the existing ones (in php) in the email using AJAX?

Comment: @Dan when i check the url you gave me, it looks like everything is going to work fine. Form will submit and if there is no char limit for the values on the callback it will work great. Let me know if it throws any errors.